# How to restrict my google API key and use it with Google Geocoding API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-geocoder, api-key

I have a WordPress site and I am using a NPM package to call the Google Geocoding API from google and get the latitude and longitude from an address, it includes the API key and the address to look for. I had to un restrict my API key on my google console because I was getting an error when I was trying to do the call.

The package is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps

What I am trying to achieve is to restrict my API key to be used only on the site. Right now it is only restricted with Geocoding API, Javascript Maps API and Places API filters so it won't be used with any other kind of library.

I am only using the geocoding functionality on the site and nothing else so it doesn't make sense to have a Map, but I have the places and maps libraries active because on the WordPress admin I use them.

I tried the HTTP referrer restriction with the website domain name and IP address restriction with the server IP where the site is being hosted but none of these worked.

I have a googleClient object which handles the Geocoding API

```
let requested_address
googleClient.geocode({address: requested_address})
  .asPromise()
  .then((response) => {
    // Call to another function passing the location object from response
    showLocations(response.json.results[0].geometry.location)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // print error message in screen
    $('.results-message').show().html(err.json.error_message)
  });
```

I get an error with this message: 
`API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.`

I am trying to get a way to use this same package with the API Key restrictions so it is not used on other sites/apps or other way to get the location latitude and longitude, even if you just put a zip code or a non complete address as Google Geocoding does.

Comment: Are you trying to use that NPM package in the front-end of your site - e.g. is that code that you posted running in the browser versus on the server? That would explain the referrer issue; that package is [not meant to be used client-side](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js#user-content-attention), and you would be much better off using the [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Locking down the API via the Google Cloud Console, which is what you couldn't get to work, is really the best way to lock it down.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use it on the front end. I did some research and seems that I will have to use the Maps Javascript API in order to lock it with HTTP referrer as you mention. The thing is that I was trying to find a way to not use the Maps API as we don't have a map on the website and it will just cause an extra call on the cloud account and extra load to the page. Thanks for your response!